# Mapping answers to questions

Tags: typescript

Based on the following post: [Rendering a dynamic survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287841/rendering-a-dynamic-survey)

```
let questions = [{idquestion: 1, question:"age?"}, {idquestion: 2, question: "sex?"}];
let answers = [{idanswer: 1, answer:"17", idquestion: 1}, {idanswer: 2, question: "male", idquestion: 2}];
let questionanswer = {question: 'edad?', answer: '17'};
let questionsAndAnswers =
    questions.map(question => {question:question, answer: answers.find((answer) => answer.idquestion === question.idquestion)})
```

I obtain the following errors:

```
question: unused label

answer: cannot find name answer
```

I want to obtain an object `questionAndAnswers` with questions and answers related. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let questionsAndAnswers = questions.map( (question) => {
    return { question: question, answer: answers.filter( (answer) => { return answer.idquestion === question.idquestion; })[0]}
});
```

BTW Functional coding style is interesting but this method feels pretty dirty.

http://codepen.io/amishstripclub/pen/wzbYoZ?editors=0010

Comment: I think it feels a lot less dirty with a little judicious formatting (and use of the [shorthand object return syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770415/ecmascript6-arrow-function-that-returns-an-object)): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jroZyk?editors=0010

Comment: Yeah, that is better. I might refactor the answers function out to a separate function named "mapAnswerstoQuestions" or something of the sort. Then I could get the gist of what was being assigned to answers without having to mentally parse the logic out.